# Back button query, want it to return to a specific page on the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I have three activities A, B and C.

A --> B --> C. activity B isn't shown to the user, its calling an api and gathering some information.  Should the user hit back I'm hoping for it to go back to A, but not sure how this can be done?

I've already tried coroutines to get around this issue and I've not had much look.

Result is that the back button when pressed continues back to activity C and never gets back to activity A.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call *finish()* on B Activity after *startActivity(...)* call

```
    startActivity(Intent(this, C::class.java))
    this.finish()
```

Comment: It works but i recomend you to use something like an asynctask or a service to do whatever you do in "B_Activity" instead of use a "ghost activity".

Comment: Yea, do you mean Coroutines? We're really struggling with them.  Basically the API call gets longitude and latitude of two postcodes (UK), and then calculates the distance using the android Distance library. This information is then rendered on the UI.  Is it  possible to delay the loading of the UI and allow the information to return? Thanks for your help Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Activity B at all? I think there is a problem with your design. Look into android architecture components project for a good design guideline. Usually things like api calls need to be done inside classes that do not depend on Activity lifecycle, unless you need the activity lifecycle for your requirement. [Android Architecture Components "JetPack"](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#truth)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.

My UI is dependent upon the API call.  I've attempted the api call on another thread and not getting very far with it I'm afraid, it doesn't return in time to be rendered on the UI.  

Having it in Activity B does work, but it is hack really.  Myself and a fellow programmer have tried coroutines to sort the issue out and not managed it.

Comment: While the above code might work for you at the moment, Although I don't think it solves the actual problem. It's just overdosing the patient with pain killers instead of removing stress out of their life in order to not use pain killers at all. Look into implicit invocation pattern to achieve what you want. Also follow the SOLID Principle, YAGNI and DRY.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I'll definitely have a look, I get the analogy, just looking at reengineering it now. Thanks again for the advice. :)